# Can a GitHub Action know its version that was specified after @ character?

Tags: github-actions

In order to use a specific version of an action we use this syntax:

```
- name: Setup Python
  uses: actions/setup-python@v1
```

or:

```
- name: Setup Python
  uses: actions/setup-python@main
```

`v1` is the name of a tag or a branch, so the code we want to use is already there.
However, I'd like to know if there is a way to get the version string inside the YAML file that defines an action.

When we create an action, we create a repository with `action.yml`.
Now, I'd like to retrieve this "v1" or "main" string from within the code in `action.yml`.

In `action.yml`, I'd like to have:

```
runs:
  using: 'docker'
  image: 'docker://some_url_to_image:${ the retrieved "v1" or "main" here}'
```

So that I could use an image that matches the version of the action.

Is this possible?